# how do i create mysql user and database in bash script with prefix

Tags: mysql, bash, quotes

Is there anyway to do the same with prefix underscore with same username.

For example :-

```
#!/bin/bash
db_user=devdb
db_pass=`openssl rand -hex 16`
mysql -u root <<-EOF
CREATE USER '$db_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$db_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  `$db_user\_%` . * TO  '$db_user'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
EOF
```

In above script GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES giving error and i want solution for that.

If i am using below command without variables directory in mysql root then no error.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  `devdb\_%` . * TO  'devdb'@'localhost';
```

Please reply if anyone have solution to this.

Comment: What error is `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES` giving ?

Comment: Also -- Does the database exist before you `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES` ?

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 3: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* TO 'devdb'@'localhost'' at line 1

Comment: That might be the `backslash`  being interpreted by the shell, add one more to disable it's special feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try using double quotes instead of single quotes for variables.

Refer: [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: Then what I guess is happening is that in your here-string you are directly passing the values to mysql shell one by one (In this case mysql will not expand the variable and will take them literally as $db_user). Try once without using the here-string to confirm.